# Looking for examples of well-known non-waltz music definitely in 3/4 time

Tags: reference-request

I'm taking a composition class and I have to write some pieces in 3/4 time.   I'm struggling to write stuff that doesn't sound blatantly like a waltz.   So I'm looking for examples of well-known music I can study.
When I did a Google search I found lots of examples that triggered debates between different people about whether the piece in question was really in 3/4 time or 6/8 time.  So my criteria are...

1. Reasonably well-known
2. Any era or period  (pop/rock, American songbook, jazz, folk, classical, etc)
3. Definitely 3/4 either because it's overwhelmingly obvious or we know the composer notated it that way
4. NOT A WALTZ

Comment: The vast majority of music in 3/4 is not a waltz. When you're composing just avoid anything that has (or implies) the typical waltz accompaniment.

Comment: There seems to be some disagreement about the time signauture, but I think listening to the Beatles "Norwegian Wood" could be helpful.  Whether it's in 3/4, 6/8 or (my favorite argument) "slow" 12/8 :) I think it gives a sense of how a song can use a 3/4 pace without sounding too much like a waltz.

Comment: I found this too, which might be fun to sample... https://www.betamonkey.com/popular-examples-of-music-written-in-3-4/  The Hal David, Burt Bacharach song "What the World Needs Now" is one I hadn't thought of...

Comment: Do minuets count?  Sarabandes are in 3/4 but too slow to be mistaken for a waltz.  The same is true of the loure, an example of which is found in Bach's French Suite no. 5.

Answer (score 2):

Chopin's *Mazurkas*.

Schubert's *Landlers* and *German Dances*.

Middle movements of piano sonatas from Haydn or Mozart.

Also, just peruse a traditional songbook or hymnal, there will be 3/4 songs like Happy Birthday, The Star Spangled Banner, or God Save the King.

> ...debates between different people about whether the piece in question was really in 3/4 time or 6/8 time

That would be a debate between people who don't know the difference between *simple* meter 3/4 and *compound* meter 6/8, 3/4 has three strong pulses, three beats, but 6/8 has two. Those two meters are distinctively different.

However, the difference between 3/4, 3/2 and 3/8 is more subtle. All have 3 beats, but historically each meter was used for a different characteristic feel. The essential idea is during the Baroque period meters with smaller bottom numbers were played in slower tempos. You can group them together as simple, triple meters.

If triple meter is what you want, and not specifically just 3/4, you could also look at the dance called the *sarabande* which is in 3/2 or the *courtante* which is sometimes in 3/2, sometimes in 3/4. Both dances were common movements in the Baroque dance suite.

> ...I'm struggling to write stuff that doesn't sound blatantly like a waltz.

This may also have to do with "waltz style" accompaniment which is the "bass, chord, chord" pattern. You can try to escape that two ways:

- write a melodic bass, minuet and courtante dances will provide examples
- try a non-waltz tempo

Some Romantic era dances like the mazurka or lander may sound waltz-like, because they often use the bass, chord, chord pattern. If you want to avoid that, definitely look to Baroque dance examples.

Comment: The reason why I want to avoid debates about  3/4 -vs- 6/8 time is because I intend to buy the (original, correct, from the music publisher, etc) sheet music to study it in depth.   So I want to make sure before I spend the money I'm really getting something the composer intended to be in 3/4, and not just something that sounds like it to someone's ear.   ...PS... I was surprised this got migrated to "fans" because it's about composition, not "listening or "appreciating".

Comment: Only something badly written in 6/8 *may* be considered to be waltz time, which virtually always is written properly in 3/4.

Comment: @user316117, I agree, the composition part of your question should have kept it on the music practice and theory exchange.

Comment: @user316117: What you want to do with that information does not influence what is needed to answer the question; I see no composing aspect involved in creating a list of non-waltz 3/4 pieces.

Comment: I don't think *landler* is a good example, since it's *an Austrian folk dance in triple time, a precursor of the waltz* You would be hard-pressed to distinguish some landler from waltzes just by listening. Technically yes, you can say if  *ländler* is in the title it isn't  a *waltz*, but it may feel like one.

Comment: @DjinTonic, that's why I made the broader point about avoiding waltz style accompaniment. That pattern is the main issue, not a title name.

Comment: Sarabandes may also be written in 3/4, unless my memory fails me.

Comment: @user316117 you might find study of Sondheim's _A Little Night Music_ to be instructive.  It is almost entirely written in either triple meter or compound meter.

Comment: @phoog, sure, sarabande, 3/2, 3/4 basically simple, triple time

Answer (score 1):

#### Classical

- Try Minuets by Bach and Mozart, who wrote particularly well-known ones.
- Many of Beethoven's Bagatelles are in 3/4, and "Fur Elise" is in 3/8, which for your purposes may also be useful.
- Chopin's Mazurkas, Scherzos, and Polonaises are in 3/4.
- Schubert's Impromptus Op. 90 Nos. 2 & 4; Op. 142 No. 2 & 4 (#4 is 3/8)

#### Jazz

- check out "Bluesette" by Toots Thielemans
- "Lover" by Rogers and Hart
- "Up Jumped Spring" by Freddie Hubbard
- "Blues to Elvin" by John Coltrane
- "Afro Blue" by Mongo Santamaría.

#### Pop/Rock

- "Que Sera, Sera"
- "Are You Lonesome Tonight?"
- "The Times They Are A-Changin'"
- "Manic Depression"
  ... actually, I'm just pulling these from [Popular Examples of Music Written in 3/4 Time](https://www.betamonkey.com/popular-examples-of-music-written-in-3-4/).

Comment: For a classical piece that's not like _any_ dance form, how about Bach's [Prelude VI in D minor, BWV875](https://youtu.be/0RZ5N6hVYA8)? (In fact, there are many more in 3/4 in Book II of [the Forty-Eight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Well-Tempered_Clavier), amongst a wide range of other key signatures.)

Answer (score 1):

A curious case is the [Finale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McdK9K3mIEU) in  Schumann's *Carnaval,* Op.9 -- *Marche des "Davidsbündler" Contre les Philistins*.  Schumann is having fun writing a "march" in 3/4 !

LEFT right LEFT **|** right LEFT right **|** LEFT right LEFT **|** right ...